# Explanation for Perl syntax needed

Tags: perl

I have a line in a code something like that:

```
my $thefilename  = ${'myConfig::connection' . $argument}{thefilename};
```

the `thefilename` is passed through another file. Can someone elaborate what does `'myConfig::connection'` part means? and what does that `${}{};` part mean?

This is legacy code and I am pretty much new to Perl.

Comment: are those not hash keys? try printing/dumping ${'myConfig::connection' . $argument}. the value should be the filename.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is constructing a variable name for a hash, then making a single element reference to a hash. This is called a "soft reference", and something that's typically frowned upon nowadays because there are better ways to accomplish that.

A single element access to a hash looks like this, where the hash variable has already been defined (or maybe not defined yet in the absence of `strict`):

```
my %hash_name;
$hash_name{$key}
```

There a syntax for dereferencing a hash reference where you surround the reference in braces then access the key you want. This is the tedious old "circumfix" notation:

```
my $ref = { a => 1, ... };
${ $ref }{$key};
```

If that value in `$ref` is not a reference, Perl can use the simple string value in that variable as the variable name. This is a soft reference (and one of the things disallowed by `use strict`):

```
my $ref = 'hash_name';
${ $ref }{$key};
```

You don't want to do this unless you know what you are doing, which is why `strict` warns you about it.

But you can put the string directly in the braces and skip the variable:

```
${ 'hash_name' }{$key}
```

Or construct the string inside the braces:

```
${ 'hash' . '_' . 'name' }{$key}
```

In your case, you end up with:

```
${'myConfig::connection' . $argument}{thefilename};
```